# php variable in jquery.ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, text

I have a form in a php file that takes user entered values and sends the data into a .txt file.

Now it works fine when the form is filled, the 'submit' button is clicked and the user is sent to a 'confirmation/completed' page, whilst the data received is put into a .txt file.

What i want to do is use ajax and jquery to have the form => completed/confirmation without being sent to the other page.

The problem is the user data is not being transmitted now to the .txt file.

PHP: (confirmation.php)

```
<?php
  $color = $_POST['color'];
  $fp = fopen('userdata.txt', 'w');
  $valstring = "What Color: " . $color . "\r\n";
  fwrite($fp, $valstring);
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

AJAX/JQUERY: (button clicked from form.php)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var cir = {
    load: $('<div />', { class: 'loading' }),
    contain: $('#contain')
}

$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'confirmation.php',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function() {
            cir.contain.append(cir.load);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            cir.contain.html(data);
        }
    });
});

});
```

When using the ajax above the userdata.txt file only has the `What Color:` entered into it. The `$color` value that the user selected has not been recognised.

I know the code works without the ajax, but i would like to have the ajax (no page refresh) method, if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `data` parameter in your ajax call, something like this should work:

```
<form>
   <select name="color" id="color">
      <option value="Red">Red</option>
      <option value="Green">Green</option>
   </select>
   <select id="age">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" id="name" />
   <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>

$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
     url:'confirmation.php', 
     type:'POST',
     // get the selected values from 3 form fields
     data:'color=' + $('#color').val() + 
          '&age=' + $('#age').val() + 
          '&name=' + $('#name').val(),
     success:function(data) {
        // ...
     }
  });
  return false;
});
```

You should probably read more about [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. My form has the `method="POST"` and `action="confirmation.php"` set. Is that needed? Also, my user values received are from `selects`. The user values are taken from drop down options, does that change things?

Comment: Nope it isn't needed if you're sending the data through ajax. Just try it and see how it works. If your have a select field you should set the `id` of the field to `color` for the above code to work. The `return false` part will stop the form from being sent in ordinary fashion.

Comment: Okay, using your code the value is being sent to the confirmation.php page (i used the `echo` function to check), but the userdata.txt file is empty. The `$valstring = "What Color: " . $color . "\r\n";` is not recognised. The value is being carried over though.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I made an error. It does work. Thank You. One question though. If I have more than one form element, another `select`, `input` etc. How do I write in the `data:` line, to accommodate for multiple `id` fields?

Comment: @user1648449 - I updated the answer so it now sends data from 3 different form fields

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending any data in your ajax post, for this reason the variable $color it's empty in the confirmation.php
try changing this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'confirmation.php',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function() {
        cir.contain.append(cir.load);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        cir.contain.html(data);
    }
```

with:

```
var formColor = $("#colorId").val(); //where ColorId it's the color input type ID 
$.ajax({
    url: 'confirmation.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { color: formColor },
    beforeSend: function() {
        cir.contain.append(cir.load);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        cir.contain.html(data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work. Maybe I've messed up something in my code. I'm using `select` and `option` tags, as my values are listed in drop-downs.